# How to get a user's username and use it with filedialog.askdirectory?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, filedialog

I would like python to find the current user's username and then implement it into the following line of code.

I have used multiple suggestions given on here but they don't seem to work, the only thing that works is when I manually enter the username in below line of code starting with `root = filedialog…` then the folder opens up in the `C:\Users\username\Documents` as it should.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import getpass
import os

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry('200x400')

#user input
root = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="C:\\Users\\username\\Documents", title="Select your root 
folder")

def printName(event):
    print("Config folder created")
    #Create a folder structure
    project = "1"
    app = "bl"
    mw = "jb"
    a = "modules"
    b = "com"
    c = "mac"
    d = "f"
    e = "config"
    f = "main"

    path = f"{root}/{project}/{app}/{mw}/{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}/{e}/{f}".lower().replace(" ","")
    print(path)

    #If path exists don't create if not create path
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
        print("Config folder created")

button_1 = Button(gui, text="Config folder")
button_1.bind("<Button-1>", printName)
button_1.pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: On Windows there's an environment variable named `USERNAME` you could use — i.e. the value `os.environ['USERNAME']`. It's probably in the Windows registry somewhere, too, to that's another way.

Comment: Open a command prompt and issue `set USER` command and see whether `USERNAME` and `USERPROFILE` environment variables are set or not.

Comment: This is asking the wrong question. You are looking for the user-configurable location of a well-known folder. [Working with Known Folders in Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/working-with-known-folders) explains how to do that properly.

Comment: Yes if I go to CMD and type set user the the USERNAME and USERPROFILE environment variables are set.
However when I use os.environ['USERNAME'] in the code above it still doesn't work.
Looking to pass this programme on so whoever has this programme it will work on  their PC and pick up their respective user name.

Comment: Note that the name of your home directory under `C:\Users` may not exactly the same as the value of env `USERNAME`.  My username is "acw1668", but the name of the home directory inside `C:\Users` is "acw16".  Better use env `USERPROFILE`.  Also update your question how you use `os.environ[...]`.

Comment: Many thanks acw that worked!  This now opens in the USERPROFILE C:\Users\username,  I tried adding on \\Documents but that didn't work anything else I have to add on in order for it to open in the username's documents folder?

Comment: `initialdir=f"{os.environ['USERPROFILE']}\\Documents"` should work.

Comment: Yes ACW that works perfectly now thanks!  Was there anything I was doing wrong?